# How do I detect the IP of my remote server?

Tags: php, apache, ip

If I have a first PHP file, activated by a front-end react app, which calls a second PHP file (which has to access a database and, thus, I want users not to be able to detect it, by hiding it with some PHP rule), how can I get the IP of the Apache server itself (in PHP language, of course), in order to prevent any attack from outer of the server itself?

I would like to implement some PHP API not publicly accessible externally of the server, that's all.

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];` This should do the trick.

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov  So, if I compare the Ip obtained by "$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']" and the one coming from the request, they should always be the same, right?

Comment: If they are on the same Server, then yes

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov  Perfect, that's exaclty what I was looking for. If you write it as a regular answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` should do the trick.